# Android in-app payment: User set price

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Is there a way in Google In-app payment API, to set the item's price from the app?

I'd like to create a donate-my-app button in my app. There'll be some pre-defined donation amounts (eg 1$, 5$, 10$, and so on).

But I'd like to offer a donation method, where my users can choose how many money will they donate to me. Is there a way to impelent this in Google In-app payment service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, not possible.

From the **Google Play Console**, you can set pre-defined **SKUs** for each amount.
Then, list those amounts in your app. Whenever a user selects one amount, make them actually "purchase" that **SKU** item. That way you get the money (minus the fee Google applies).

Other than that, if you want custom amounts, Try **PayPal**. It has an Android SDK https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK. (Personally, never used it).

Comment: I wouldn't use PayPal or any other method as your app may get blocked by Google. It's pretty clear on their T&C now, that you are not allow to use anything than their in-app products.